# DRF Modelserialize returns only key

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using **Django 1.5** and **Django REST Framework 2**

I have overridden `create` method to add validation and return Response manually.

my view is like

```
class MultiUserCreateListView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    model = MultiUser
    serializer_class = MultiUserSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        users = MultiUser.objects.get_shared_users(user=self.request.user)
        return users

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        email = request.DATA.get('email', None)
        access_level = request.DATA.get('access_level', None)
        name = request.DATA.get('name', None)

        user = User.objects.filter(email=email)
        if user:
            return  Response({'message': 'Email address already in use.'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.DATA)

        new_user = create_active_user(request, self, email, email, password=None, is_shared=True)

        if new_user:
            if serializer.is_valid():
                multi_user_obj = MultiUser(
                    user=self.request.user,
                    shared_user=new_user,
                    access_level=access_level
                )
                multi_user_obj.save()

                serializer2 = MultiUserSerializer(data=multi_user_obj)
                return Response(serializer2.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response({'message': 'Unable to create user. Try again'})
```

But the response contains only key with empty value for the fields defined in the `MultiUserSerializer`

```
{"id": "", "shared_user_name": "", "shared_user_email": "", "access_level": "", "invitation_sent_on": null, "invitation_accepted_on": null, "is_invitation_sent": "", "is_invitation_accepted": "", "created": null, "updated": null}
```

While printing `print(multi_user_obj.id)` gives the correct id.

**Why is it not serializing?**

> Edit 2: Serializer

```
class MultiUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    shared_user_email = serializers.Field(source='shared_user.email')
    shared_user_name = serializers.Field(source='shared_user.first_name')
    is_invitation_sent = serializers.Field(source='is_invitation_sent')
    is_invitation_accepted = serializers.Field(source='is_invitation_accepted')

    class Meta:
        model = MultiUser
        fields = (
            'id', 'shared_user_name', 'shared_user_email',
            'access_level', 'invitation_sent_on', 'invitation_accepted_on',
            'is_invitation_sent', 'is_invitation_accepted',
            'created', 'updated'
        )
```

Comment: can you show MultiUserSerializer code!

Comment: Check **Edit 2**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mush pass your instance by `instance` not by `data`

```
serializer2 = MultiUserSerializer(instance=multi_user_obj)
```